# UIModalPresentationFormSheet and tableView contentInset

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a tableView inside a viewController.

This viewController is presented with `presentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

When the keyboard appears on screen, I don't understand how to set the correct inset to the tableview to avoid cells being covered up by the keyboard.

With fullscreen viewcontroller, I use the keyboard notifications to get the keyboard's frame and do the math.

How may I calculate the covered area?